# how to implement a viewpager to load images from server side?

Tags: java, android

I have written a server side program in jsp to insert images into my database and its working fine. 
Now i want to load the images from the URL inside a `ViewPager`(client side)
I have written a `CustomPagerAdapter` class and have an activity in which i want to call the pager adapter class, i am getting an error **Cannot decode stream FileNotFoundException**
please help me to figure out how to solve the problem and how to implement a `ViewPager`.

**CustomPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
ArrayList<String> imgUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
Bitmap bitmap;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageURL) {
    mContext = context;

    this.imgUrl = imageURL;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgUrl.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == ((RelativeLayout) arg1);
}

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, 
    false);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUrl.get(position), options);
    TouchImageView imgview = (TouchImageView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgEvent);
    imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
```

**EventType_Images.java** : Here i have converted the String imgUrl to arraylist , is it right ? if not please tell me the correct way

```
public class EventType_Images extends Activity {

TextView txtHeader;
String passedData, passedData1;
public static String imgURL;
String images;
ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<String> imgList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventtype_images);
    passedData = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    passedData1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    txtHeader.setText(passedData1);
    images = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageName");
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    imgURL = "http://197.188.1.50:8082/Server/Gallery/" + images;
    imgList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imgURL));

    new MyAsyncTask(this,  
    imgList).execute("http://197.188.1.50:8082/Server/Gallery/"+ images);

}
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {

private Context context;
private ViewPager viewPager;
CustomPagerAdapter adapter;

public MyAsyncTask(Context context, ArrayList<String> imgList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
    this.imgList = imgList;
}

protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL imgUrl = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        imgUrl = new URL(EventType_Images.imgURL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);// Convert to bitmap
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return adapter;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    // imgview.setImageBitmap(bm);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context,imgList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Error

02-24 17:00:57.492: E/BitmapFactory(12895): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/197.188.1.50:8082/Server/Gallery/1.jpg2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
the image names are also coming one after the other

Thanking You

Comment: It looks like you have a `[` in front of the image name. It also looks like you have more than one filename i.e. `1.jpg2.jpg` so sort out the contents of `images`

Comment: the [ was put by mistake , yes sir in my database i have 4 to 5 branch names like computers , electronics etc , and that is why i want a viewpager so that if i insert images in the same branch , i can view it with the help of a viewpager

Comment: Try this library.
http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3680

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your log entry was accurately listed here, the URL seems wrong:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/http:/197.188.1.50:8082/Server/Gallery/[1.jpg2.jpg
```

This does not look like a proper URL.

Also, you asked if it's correct to convert the string to an `ArrayList`. This code is very strange. You are keeping a list as a static member in your activity, and it's being referenced by your `AsyncTask`, instead of just passing it along to your `AsyncTask`. `doInBackground` has support for parameters passed into the task - use it!

You should typically never expose any data from an activity as a static member as it does not respect activity life cycle etc.

I would start by verifying that you are passing the right URL. Fix your `AsyncTask` so that you are passing along the parameters you need, remove your statically exposed members, and add a log entry in `doInBackground` that prints the URL you are trying to connect to. As we have no idea what your "images" parameter in the intent is holding, it's hard to say what you are really passing into that list - but in any case it will always be a list of ONE element.

Comment: sir the [ was by mistake , sir i have edited the code , but i am getting an error in viewpager.setadapter(adapter);

Comment: Well the URL is just as strange now, it starts with a slash

`/http:/xxx`

instead of

`http://xxx`

etc.
Please post more details and review what you are trying to accomplish with that list etc.

Comment: the url is working properly sir , but i am getting an error in onpostexecute , if the url was wrong i wouldnt had got connection inside my doinbackground method

Comment: Before trying to achieve viewpager , i tried to view only a single image which was displaying properly but i want to view multiple images of the same event which was not displaying , so i thought viewpager is the best option to view multiple images , as there are multiple images in my database of a particular event

Comment: images                     message            created-at                             event

941lakshmivishnu.jpg test message 2015-02-15 22:04:45 CSI
vitthala-photo-3.jpg   hello message 2015-02-22 22:28:21 PESA
Ranganath1-v.jpg      csi test message 2015-02-24 16:26:48 CSI

this is how my database looks sir , and the same event list (CSI , PESA) i have in my android listview and when i click on CSI , i want to view the images in viewpager , this is what i am trying to implement sir , if possible for you , guide me to achieve it

Comment: Again, with the current information, helping is hopeless. You are creating a list holding ONE element and I don't know what string you are passing in the "images" variable. Also, it's evident that the url is corrupt. Please add logs printing the url in doInBackground and add logcat log.